# Calculate number of characters of the line of contenteditable div where caret is on

Tags: jquery, html

I have a contentEditable div.I want to get the number of characters of the line where my caret would be active and output it on the textarea in real time.Im new to jquery so i don't know at all how to do it.Can you help me figure out how to achieve this?

```
<div class="article"  contentEditable=true ></div>
<textarea id="output"></textArea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this and you're done...

```js
$('.article').on("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
  var len = $('.article').text().length;
  $('#output').val(len);
});
```

```css
.article {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  background:#EEE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="article"  contentEditable=true ></div>
<textarea id="output"></textArea>
```

Comment: This gives the whole number of characters in the div.i want to get characters of seperate lines specifically the line where my caret would be on.